# concave function property

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I read that, a function $f$ is concave if and only if,

$f(a+t) - f(a) \geq f(b+t)-f(b), \forall a,b, 0< a < b, t>0$

How do we get this result ?. It does not sound very evident from the definition of concave functions.  Does this mean that, for any convex function

$f(a+t) - f(a) \leq f(b+t)-f(b), \forall a,b, 0< a < b, t>0$

Comment: Don't you need $t\ge 0$?

Comment: yes. corrected the question.

Comment: It is a well known result. It says the differential quotient (and therefore also the derivative) of a convex function is monotonous increasing. Draw a picture. That usually helps

Comment: @user251257, coming back to your answer. the fact that slope and hence derivative (in 2d case), is increasing for a convex function and decreasing for a concace function. This fact is true irrespective of the domain values, right ?.  I just worked out with a drawing, and it seems the positive constrains are necessary for the differential quotient case. But it is not necessary in case of derivative. Why it is so ?